# 2.4GHz signal through 900MHz amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, rf, vco

Nobbie question, but I was wondering:
if I were to generate 2400MHz signal in VCO and put it through, let's say 900MHz RF amplifier, will the output signal be 900MHz?

Or would this experiment fry the amp or vco?

Or nothing would happen at all, no signal, no damage?

Comment: To a 1st approximation, no signal. Damage is optional.

Comment: If the VCO is a pure tone at 2.4GHz, you'll likely get nothing out. If filters simply changed the frequency of stop band components, nothing in RF engineering today would work!

Comment: Add a mixer and downconvert to 900MHz first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly happens would absolutely 100% depend on the RF Amplifier (and VCO).

In many cases though, an amplifier designed for a 900MHz centre band will have transistors that are fast enough for, let's say 1200MHz, maybe 1.5GHz. Which means at the least trying to get them to work at their designed set points at nearly three times the design frequency will have them heat up and possibly get damaged. It's not generally a great idea to try it without knowing any specifics.

What's sure, though, is that putting in a 2.4GHz signal will almost certainly not get you a clean 900MHz output. There may be some 900MHz induced oscillation per chance, but it will most certainly not be clean and probably not very strong either.

Comment: Thank you.
I also would like to know if it's possible in any way to split single VCO output frequency into 3 different frequencies and amplify them separately?

Comment: In a continuous time-domain system there is no "splitting of a single frequency". If you are making a 2.4GHz square wave, you can get a 2.4GHz sine + over tone sines out of it, maybe an undertone or two at very low levels. What you are asking is frequency division circuitry or Phase Locked Loops to _create a **new**_ frequency in phase with the original.